# Get Square corners from 2 points

Tags: java, math, points

I have 2 values and want to create a rectangle from it.

[image]

So let's say:
1 = 1,1
2 = 10,8

So I want to calculate the upper left corner which would result in **1,8** and the lower right corner which would be **10,1**.
How can I achieve this with Java? Are there any libraries for this or is it even possible with the standard equipment?

Comment: That wouldn't be a square. Do you mean a rectangle with sides that are exactly vertical or horizontal (not crooked)?

Comment: Sorry of course I mean a rectangle and not a square...

Comment: There shouldn't be any need for a library, beyond maybe a really simple `Point` class that contains an x coordinate and a y coordinate.

Comment: Your example values don't make any sense. If you have point 1 at x=1,y=1 and point 2 at x=10,y=8, you already have the upper left corner and lower right corner.

Comment: @hexafraction, I thought all rectangles have straight, not crooked lines. Or are we talking about hyperspace i.e. a galaxy far, far away?

Comment: @CocoNess I meant axis-aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your diagram and example, you want a rectangle with vertical and horizontal sides. If you look at your current example, all you did was take x1 and y2 for one of the points, and x2/y1 for the other point.

So, given `Point`s `p1` and `p2`, you could do as follows:

```
Point p3 = new Point(p1.x, p2.y);
Point p4 = new Point(p2.x, p1.y);
```

Of course, if you do not have `Point` objects you can just use the numbers as variables accordingly.

Comment: Awesome thanks alot! Veerryyy bad at math I guess... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is take the min/max x/y of the existing points:

```
Point p1 = ...
Point p2 = ...

Point upperLeft  = new Point(Math.min(p1.x, p2.x), Math.min(p1.y, p2.y));
Point lowerRight = new Point(Math.max(p1.x, p2.x), Math.max(p1.y, p2.y));
```

Note: This assumes x increases as you go right and y increases as you go down. If you have y increasing as you go up, change to:

```
Point upperLeft  = new Point(Math.min(p1.x, p2.x), Math.max(p1.y, p2.y));
Point lowerRight = new Point(Math.max(p1.x, p2.x), Math.min(p1.y, p2.y));
```

Answer (score 1):

here is some code to start with:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4;
        x1 = 1; y1 = 1;
        x3 = 10; y3 = 8;

        x4 = x1;y4 = y3;
        x2 = x3; y2 = y1;

        System.out.println("(x4,y4)=("+ x4 + "," + y4 + ")\t\t (x3,y3)=(" + x3 + "," + y3+")");
        System.out.println("(x1,y1)=("+ x1 + "," + y1 + ")\t\t (x2,y2)=(" + x2 + "," + y2+")");

    }
}
```

Result is:

```
(x4,y4)=(1,8)        (x3,y3)=(10,8)
(x1,y1)=(1,1)        (x2,y2)=(10,1)
```